# Calculate Fundamental group of this sphere plus coordinate axis

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, spheres, retraction

I'm looking to calculate the fundamental group of $X = S^2 \cup A$ where $A = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : (x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)(y^2+z^2) = 0\}$ (coordinate axis) but I can't think of how, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What should $A$ exactly be? Typo?

Comment: Fixed! Sorry for the typo

Comment: This is a sphere together with three diameters of it (you can ignore the parts of the axes outside the sphere). This looks like the sphere cut up into 8 spherical triangles together with straight lines from each vertex of these triangles to the origin. Each of these 8 subsets possesses a small enough open neighborhood deformation retracting onto it and these neighborhoods have path-connected pairwise and triplewise intersections, so an application of Seifert-van Kampen seems called for.

Comment: $X \simeq S^2 \vee\bigvee_7 S^1$